Why a probability distribution in RHS in deriving Bell's Inequality?
Why is there typically an integral over a probability distribution in the RHS of a derivation of Bell's inequality
$$|P(\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{b}) - P(\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{c})| \leq \int{p(\lambda)[1 - A(\boldsymbol{b}, \lambda) A(\boldsymbol{c}, \lambda)] \mathrm{d}\lambda}?$$
I would think the definitive notion of a hidden variable would make things deterministic.

@Vincent Thacker how do I save your kind edit?

Not to take anything away from the other correct answers, but perhaps this may add a bit.  You said:

I would think the definitive notion of a hidden variable would make
things deterministic.

This is a correct viewpoint, or at least conceivable at the time of Bell's paper.  The important historical point is that the 1935 EPR paper essentially "proved" that there were deterministic outcomes for quantum measurements on entangled particle pairs.  They did that by demonstrating that a measurement on one of a pair (Alice) would lead you to predict with certainty the outcome on the other of a pair (Bob) if measured on the same basis.  Alice can select/measure any basis (without affecting Bob) and predict Bob's outcomes.  Therefore Bob's outcome for the basis Alice selects must be pre-determined (deterministic, as you say).
And if Bob was measured on some other basis than Alice, well, we might guess that outcome was predetermined too.  This was the EPR concept, and it seems reasonable on the face of it.  Alice and Bob's independent measurements would then form a Product State, where the statistical prediction for Alice times the statistical prediction for Bob would equal the combined statistical prediction for both Alice and Bob.  This is, of course, standard probability theory, completely classical.  Because the choice of Alice's measurement basis shouldn't impact the outcome of Bob's measurement on some different basis, right?
All this being pre-Bell. Bell's insight was that this could not be the case when more than 2 different bases were considered.  As another answer says: We assume the truth of the hypothesis (deterministic explanation) and then derive a contradiction.  That contradiction arises immediately when a third basis is thrown into the mix along with the other two. After all, the EPR viewpoint is that ALL possible outcomes were predetermined, not just the ones that were actually observed.  (This was an explicit assumption of EPR, by the way.)  Bell's use of 3 variables - a, b, and c - shows what happens mathematically when the EPR hypothesis is extended to this logical point.
And why is that?  How could the EPR hypothesis have appeared so true, but be so false?
The quantum mechanical expectation value (its prediction) is contextual.  Meaning the choice of measurement bases is the driver of the statistical prediction.  Measuring on the same basis for Alice and Bob - as was contemplated by EPR - is a special case!  In that one special case, the statistical prediction is 100% certain.  But... only in that case.  So it appears deterministic, but that is just an artifact of a more significant element of QM - that being contextuality.  No one knows precisely how contextuality works as a mechanism, but that it is contextual has been known for a long time.
So when considering all possible combinations of measurement bases: it's EPR determinism vs. QM contextuality; and non-classical contextuality wins.  Bell's formula is the general case for EPR, and this was shown to unable to match the general case for QM.  (Experiments, of course, confirm QM.)

I appreciate all the really informative answers; the mention of the importance of the third variable is especially valuable

The idea of a deterministic hidden variables theory is that if you knew the hidden variables, then you could predict the outcome without using probabilities. However, in practice, we don't observe the hidden variables. Therefore, we model our uncertainty in the values of the hidden variables by a probability distribution over their possible values. This probability distribution is very much like the distribution over microstates that appears in statistical mechanics; it describes our lack of knowledge of the precise variables necessary to specify the system exactly. In this framework, the randomness of quantum mechanics is supposed to be completely explained by the distribution over hidden variables; the probabilistic predictions of quantum mechanics are not fundamentally part of nature, but expressing this distribution over unknown hidden variables.
What Bell's theorem shows, is that if we assume the hidden variables are local in addition to deterministic (meaning that we can move two entangled parts of a system to spacelike separated distances where the hidden variables could not communicate with each other), is that there is no probability distribution over (local, deterministic) hidden variables that can violate Bell's inequalities. What is remarkable is that the theorem doesn't need to know anything about what the hidden variables are, or how many there are, or what their dynamics are. It is simply impossible to violate Bell's inequalities in a framework where we describe reality as some probability distribution over unknown, local, deterministic hidden variables. Since quantum mechanics does violate Bell's inequalities, and since experiment agrees with quantum mechanics, barring conspiracy theories, it must be that quantum mechanics is not a local, deterministic hidden variable theory.

I don't understand why you keep using the word "deterministic". Bell's theorem is not limited to deterministic theories. (You can't evade it by simply making your theory nondeterministic.)

@benrg The last sentence in the OP's question made me think they were most interested in the case of a local, deterministic hidden variable theory. I was explaining why Bell's theorem would involve a probability distribution in this case. I think it's more obvious why you would have a probability distribution if the theory was non-deterministic to start with. Of course I agree that non-determinism alone doesn't get you out of Bell's theorem, which is why I put the world "local" in bold in my second paragraph :)

The whole point of Bell's Theorem is to show that certain quantum observables do not obey any joint probability distribution, and therefore cannot be classical random variables, hidden or otherwise.
To prove that a thing does not exist, one starts by assuming that it does exist, and then derives a contradiction.
Edited to add: Maybe this example will help:
You have two cups, called A and B. Whenever you look under just one cup or the other, you find a blue marble.  Whenever you look under both cups at once, you find two red marbles.
A system of "hidden variables" would be a marble under each cup whose color might or might not change from time to time, maybe deterministically, maybe non-deterministically.
A "joint probability distribution" consists of four numbers: The probability that the marbles are currently Blue/Blue, or Blue/Red, or Red/Blue, or Red/Red.  These numbers must add to 1.
If there are hidden variables, then there is a joint probability distribution. The joint probability distribution might or might not be changing all the time, or occasionally, or never. It's still a joint probability distribution, and it still indicates the existence of hidden variables.
Here is a proof that in the cup/marble scenario, there is no joint probability distribution.  Start by assuming there is one.

The probability of Blue/Blue must be zero, because when you look under both cups, you always see reds.  
The probability of Blue/Red must be zero, because whenever you look under just Cup B, you always see Blue. 
 The probability of Red/Blue must be zero, because whenever you look under just Cup A, you always see Blue.
The probability of Red/Red must be zero, because whenever you look under just Cup A or Cup B, you always see Blue.

Because all four probabilities are zero, they can't add to 1.  That contradiction rules out the existence of a joint probability distribution, which is the same thing as saying that it rules out hidden variables.
That's a case of Bell's Theorem, and the poof I just gave echoes the structure of the proof you're trying to read --- start by assuming a joint probability distribution, and derive a contradiction.
Of course real world marbles never behave that way because in everyday life, there are joint probability distributions for everything, so everything we see can always be modeled with hidden (or sometimes non-hidden) variables.  But quantum objects behave quite differently.

Maybe you would please elaborate as to "joint." Is that the same as "any," joint or otherwise?

"Joint" means that it specifies probabilities for various combinations of outcomes, such as $P(a,c)$.
